# Beautifulsoup: itterate over a list from a to z and parse the data in order to store it in a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, request

i am currently ironing out a very very easy parser that goes from a to z on a memberlist :: we have a memberlist here:

see: https://vvonet.vvo.at/vvonet_mitgliederverzeichnisneu

note: we have to open the link "kontaktinformationen" and scrape the data there to a pandas df

Well i think that i can do this with python beautifulsoup request and either print it to screen or store it in a df.

first of all, the script should fetch the member list page, extracts the links to individual member pages, visits each member's "kontaktinformationen" page, and subsequently it  should extract the contact information.
Finally, i think it is best to store the contact information in a DataFrame.
Well - i finally am able to print the DataFrame to the screen or save it to a CSV file.

here is my attempt:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# first,  we send a GET request to the member list page
url = "https://vvonet.vvo.at/vvonet_mitgliederverzeichnisneu"
response = requests.get(url)

# here a check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content of the page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    
    # Find now all member links
    member_links = soup.find_all("a", class_="font1")
    
    # now - Initialize lists to store data
    member_data = []
    
    # Iterate over member links
    for member_link in member_links:
        # Get the URL of the "kontaktinformationen" page
        member_url = "https://vvonet.vvo.at" + member_link["href"] + "/kontaktinformationen"
        
        # Send a GET request to the member's "kontaktinformationen" page
        member_response = requests.get(member_url)
        
        # Check if the request was successful
        if member_response.status_code == 200:
            # Parse the HTML content of the page
            member_soup = BeautifulSoup(member_response.content, "html.parser")
            
            # Find the contact information section
            contact_info_div = member_soup.find("div", class_="contact")
            
            # Check if contact information section exists
            if contact_info_div:
                # Extract the contact information
                contact_info_text = contact_info_div.get_text(separator="\n", strip=True)
                member_data.append(contact_info_text)
            else:
                member_data.append("Contact information not found")
        else:
            member_data.append(f"Failed to retrieve contact information for {member_link.text.strip()}")
    
    # Create a DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(member_data, columns=["Contact Information"])
    
    # Display the DataFrame
    print(df)
    
    # Alternatively, you can save the DataFrame to a CSV file
    # df.to_csv("member_contact_information.csv", index=False)
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve the member list page.")
```

But at the moment i get a empty dataframe..

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Contact Information]
Index: []
```

Comment: Try printing `soup` to see the html of the page and to check if you've extracted it right, using print debugging is super helpful for finding logic errors in your code

Comment: hi there - sure thing this is definitly a great food for thougth - breaking the whole steps into pieces and doing a detailed view on the data. I will take asll your tipps into account. Many many thanks for steppin up the plate. I am very glad for encouraging ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from different URL (in XML format):

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://vvonet.vvo.at/vvo/vvonet_website.nsf/allMitglieder?ReadViewEntries="

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "xml")

data = []
for e in soup.select("viewentry"):
    t = {}
    for d in e.select("entrydata"):
        t[d["name"]] = d.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
    data.append(t)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                                                             docTitle                           globUNID     docBundesland                                                                             docFachbereich                                               docFax                                        docInternet                                                 docMail                                docOrt                                                          docStrasse                                           docTelefon                                                                                               docUnternehmen
0                                                                                             Acredia Versicherung AG  x095DA0F5F9E395B0C1258A4A0037FD66              Wien                                                                         Schadenversicherer                                                                                   http://www.acredia.at                                       office@acredia.at                             1010 Wien                                                 Himmelpfortgasse 29                                     +43/(0)5 01 02-0                                                                                      Acredia Versicherung AG
1                                                                          AIG Europe S.A. - Direktion für Österreich  xFB78910F9D0D7FC7C1258A4A0037FCED              Wien                                                                                                                              +43/1/533 25 00-80                               http://www.aig.co.at                                info.oesterreich@aig.com                             1010 Wien                                                   Herrengasse 1 - 3                                      +43/1/533 25 00                                                                    AIG Europe S.A.\nDirektion für Österreich
2                                                                                                        Allianz Care  x7B60F7881DF6129AC1258A4A0037FD61                                                                                   Außerordentliches Mitglied                                                                             http://www.allianz-care.com                                                                                 IRL-Dublin 12                                    15 Joyce Way, Park West Business                                     +44/7825/510 814                                                                                                 Allianz Care
3                                                                                                  Allianz Commercial  xA362FDC72B76421DC1258A4A0037FD43              Wien                                                                                                                             +43/(0)59009-402 14                  http://www.commercial.allianz.com                               stefanie.thiem@allianz.at                             1100 Wien                                                 Wiedner Gürtel 9-13                                   +43/(0)59009-88700                                                                                           Allianz Commercial
4                                                            Allianz Elementar Lebensversicherungs-Aktiengesellschaft  xD41EC8AF73F7ED93C1258A4A0037FCE5              Wien                                                                                                                             +43/(0)5 9009-70700                              http://www.allianz.at                 feedback@allianz.at, schaden@allianz.at                             1100 Wien                                                 Wiedner Gürtel 9-13                                      +43/(0)5 9009-0                                                     Allianz Elementar Lebensversicherungs-Aktiengesellschaft
5                                                                  Allianz Elementar Versicherungs-Aktiengesellschaft  x95C137D749F4EB97C1258A4A0037FCE6              Wien                    Kfz-Versicherer Krankenversicherer Schadenversicherer Unfallversicherer                                  +43/(0)5 9009-70000                              http://www.allianz.at                 feedback@allianz.at, schaden@allianz.at                             1100 Wien                                                 Wiedner Gürtel 9-13                                      +43/(0)5 9009-0                                                           Allianz Elementar Versicherungs-Aktiengesellschaft
6                                                                                                 APK Versicherung AG  x7C2E8BD3E6C46C0BC1258A4A0037FD34              Wien                                                                          Lebensversicherer                                   +43/(0)50 275-3709                     http://www.apk-versicherung.at                                     versicherung@apk.at                             1030 Wien                                             Thomas-Klestil-Platz 13                                   +43/(0)50 275-3700                                                                                          APK Versicherung AG
7                                                                                  ARAG SE - Direktion für Österreich  xFA932E61C5D638E3C1258A4A0037FD41              Wien                                                                                                                               +43/1/531 02-1923                                 http://www.arag.at                                            info@arag.at                             1041 Wien                                    Favoritenstraße 36, Postfach 182                                       +43/1/531 02-0                                                                           ARAG SE \nDirektion für Österreich
8        Atradius Kreditversicherung - Zweigniederlassung der Atradius Crédito y Caución S.A. de Seguros y Reaseguros  xAA2CB3183BE03937C1258A4A0037FD4B              Wien                                                                                                                                                                             http://www.atradius.at                        versicherung.kredit@atradius.com                             1220 Wien                              Vienna DC Tower 1, Donau-City-Straße 7                                       +43/1/813 0313  Atradius Kreditversicherung\nZweigniederlassung der Atradius Crédito y Caución S.A. de Seguros y Reaseguros
9                                                                                       Atzbacher Versicherung V.a.G.  xF489570D29A92438C1258A4A0037FD68    Oberösterreich                                                                    Sachversicherungsverein                                    +43/7673/75488-20               http://www.atzbacher-versicherung.at                          info@atzbacher-versicherung.at      4690 Oberndorf bei Schwanenstadt                                                 Atzbacher Straße 23                                     +43/7673/75488-0                                                                                Atzbacher Versicherung V.a.G.
10                                                                         AWP P&C S.A., Niederlassung für Österreich  x3173A1D948F040D7C1258A4A0037FCEA              Wien                                                                          Unfallversicherer                                                                         http://www.allianz-partners.com                                  service.at@allianz.com                             1130 Wien                                              Hietzinger Kai 101-105                   +43/1/525 03-6945 (Service Center)                                                AWP P&C S.A., Niederlassung für Österreich (Allianz Partners)

...
```

Comment: dear Andrej - many thanks for the help:  you are a real Python-expert with all that awesome knowledge that needs to see such great pathways and methods to do things .. AND you have the great great capacity to help those who need to have some help. I am very very glad to be part of this great forum - you have helped me many times. Many many thanks for all yo u do!!   - you get 10 stars our ot five  ;).
have agreat day.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easier to reduce the steps of complexity in the first place.

Hardcode the URLs you want to visit.

Test what results you get back with your request.

After this is finished, evaluate your request, use the beautiful soup lib to check for specific fields in common.

Check the results again.

Put them in pandas dataframe afterwards.

Dont do three things (which can obviously terrible wrong) in one step.

Comment: good day dear Christoph - many thanks for the quick reply and for the awesome guidance - and the tipps to keep it simple. This is very very helpful I am very glad to read this. Thank you - i definitly will learn out of you tipps. 

its good to read -your tipps - and its encouraging! thank you alot!! 

keep up your awesome work here-  glad to have you here in the forums. Have a great day!!!